# Avoid namespace while Parsing xml with woodstox

Tags: java, xml, stax, woodstox

I am trying to parse an xml File and remove namespaces and prefix using woodstox parser(the xml contains nested elements and each element contains namespace at every level)

Below is the code i use to parse.I get the same input as i pass.Please help in resolving the issue

```
byte[] byteArray = null;
        try {
            File file = new File(xmlFileName);
            byteArray = new byte[(int) file.length()];
            byteArray = FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(file);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }

        InputStream articleStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(byteArray);


        WstxInputFactory xmlInputFactory = (WstxInputFactory) XMLInputFactory.newInstance();

        xmlInputFactory.configureForSpeed();
        // xmlInputFactory.configureForXmlConformance();
        XMLStreamReader2 xmlStreamReader = (XMLStreamReader2) xmlInputFactory.createXMLStreamReader(articleStream,
                StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name());

        xmlStreamReader.setProperty(XMLInputFactory.IS_COALESCING, true);

        WstxOutputFactory xmloutFactory = (WstxOutputFactory) XMLOutputFactory2.newInstance();

        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        XMLEventWriter xw = null;

        XMLStreamWriter2 xmlwriter = (XMLStreamWriter2) xmloutFactory.createXMLStreamWriter(sw,
                StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name());
        xmlwriter.setNamespaceContext(new NamespaceContext() {

            @Override
            public String getNamespaceURI(String prefix) {
                return "";
            }

            @Override
            public String getPrefix(String namespaceURI) {
                return "";
            }

            @Override
            public Iterator getPrefixes(String namespaceURI) {
                return null;
            }

        });


        while (xmlStreamReader.hasNext()) {
            xmlStreamReader.next();

            xmlwriter.copyEventFromReader(xmlStreamReader, false);
        }
        System.out.println("str" + xmlwriter.getNamespaceContext().getPrefix(""));

        xmlwriter.closeCompletely();
        xmlwriter.flush();

        xmlStreamReader.closeCompletely();
        xmlStreamReader.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove all namespace prefixes and bindings, you should NOT use copy methods -- they will literally copy those things. Instead read element and attribute names, but only write out using "local name"s, and leave `namespaceURI` and `prefix` as nulls (or use methods that only take local name).