# Prevent Jackson XML mapper from adding wstxns to namespaces

Tags: java, xml, jackson, jackson-dataformat-xml

When serialising objects to XML and specifying namespaces for properties using 
`@JacksonXmlRootElement(namespace = "http://...")`
Jackson will append or prepend ´wstxns1´ to the namespace. For example, say we have these classes:

**VtexSkuAttributeValues.java**

```
@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "listStockKeepingUnitName")
public class VtexSkuAttributeValues {

    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "StockKeepingUnitFieldNameDTO", namespace = "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Vtex.Commerce.WebApps.AdminWcfService.Contracts")
    @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping = false)
    private VtexSkuAttributeValue[] stockKeepingUnitFieldNameDTO;

    public VtexSkuAttributeValue[] getStockKeepingUnitFieldNameDTO() {
        return stockKeepingUnitFieldNameDTO;
    }

    public void setValues(VtexSkuAttributeValue[] values) {
        this.stockKeepingUnitFieldNameDTO = values;
    }
}
```

**VtexSkuAttributeValue.java**

```
@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "StockKeepingUnitFieldNameDTO", namespace = "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Vtex.Commerce.WebApps.AdminWcfService.Contracts")
public class VtexSkuAttributeValue {

    private String fieldName;
    private FieldValues fieldValues;
    private int idSku;

    public int getIdSku() {
        return idSku;
    }

    public String getFieldName() {
        return fieldName;
    }

    public FieldValues getFieldValues() {
        return fieldValues;
    }

    public void setIdSku(int idSku) {
        this.idSku = idSku;
    }

    public void setFieldName(String fieldName) {
        this.fieldName = fieldName;
    }

    public void setFieldValues(FieldValues fieldValues) {
        this.fieldValues = fieldValues;
    }

    @JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "fieldValues", namespace = "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Vtex.Commerce.WebApps.AdminWcfService.Contracts")
    public static class FieldValues {
        @JacksonXmlProperty(namespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays")
        @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping = false)
        public String[] string;

        public String[] getString() {
            return string;
        }

        public void setValues(String[] values) {
            this.string = values;
        }
    }
}
```

I then use the `XmlMapper` to serialise and get:

```
<listStockKeepingUnitName>
    <wstxns1:StockKeepingUnitFieldNameDTO xmlns:wstxns1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Vtex.Commerce.WebApps.AdminWcfService.Contracts">
        <fieldName>talle</fieldName>
        <fieldValues>
            <wstxns2:string xmlns:wstxns2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">6184</wstxns2:string>
        </fieldValues>
        <idSku>258645</idSku>
    </wstxns1:StockKeepingUnitFieldNameDTO>
    <wstxns3:StockKeepingUnitFieldNameDTO xmlns:wstxns3="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Vtex.Commerce.WebApps.AdminWcfService.Contracts">
        <fieldName>color</fieldName>
        <fieldValues>
            <wstxns4:string xmlns:wstxns4="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">6244</wstxns4:string>
        </fieldValues>
        <idSku>258645</idSku>
    </wstxns3:StockKeepingUnitFieldNameDTO>
</listStockKeepingUnitName>
```

Even though this is valid XML, the web service I'm working with doesn't accept it. I debugged it and it's due to the `wstxns` properties in the tags that Jackson adds for some reason.
Is there a way to prevent Jackson from adding that to the tags. The only workaround I could come up with is performing a string.replaceAll on the resulting XML but it's obviously not ideal.

Comment: Those "wstxns properties" are from the `namespace` attribute in the `JacksonXmlRootElement` annotation. Do you get the desired output if you omit the `namespace` attribute?

Comment: @dnault I can't ommit it because it's required by the web service.

Answer (score 6):

To write `XML` `Jackson` uses `javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamWriter`. You can configure instance of that class and define your own prefixes for namespaces and set default one if needed. To do that we need to extend `com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.XmlFactory` class and override a method which creates `XMLStreamWriter` instance. Example implementation could look like below:

```
class NamespaceXmlFactory extends XmlFactory {

    private final String defaultNamespace;
    private final Map<String, String> prefix2Namespace;

    public NamespaceXmlFactory(String defaultNamespace, Map<String, String> prefix2Namespace) {
        this.defaultNamespace = Objects.requireNonNull(defaultNamespace);
        this.prefix2Namespace = Objects.requireNonNull(prefix2Namespace);
    }

    @Override
    protected XMLStreamWriter _createXmlWriter(IOContext ctxt, Writer w) throws IOException {
        XMLStreamWriter writer = super._createXmlWriter(ctxt, w);
        try {
            writer.setDefaultNamespace(defaultNamespace);
            for (Map.Entry<String, String> e : prefix2Namespace.entrySet()) {
                writer.setPrefix(e.getKey(), e.getValue());
            }
        } catch (XMLStreamException e) {
            StaxUtil.throwAsGenerationException(e, null);
        }
        return writer;
    }
}
```

You can use it as below:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.io.IOContext;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationFeature;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.XmlFactory;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.XmlMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.annotation.JacksonXmlElementWrapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.annotation.JacksonXmlProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.annotation.JacksonXmlRootElement;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.util.StaxUtil;

import javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Writer;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Objects;

public class XmlMapperApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String defaultNamespace = "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Vtex.Commerce.WebApps.AdminWcfService.Contracts";
        Map<String, String> otherNamespaces = Collections.singletonMap("a", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays");

        XmlMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper(new NamespaceXmlFactory(defaultNamespace, otherNamespaces));
        xmlMapper.enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);

        System.out.println(xmlMapper.writeValueAsString(new VtexSkuAttributeValues()));
    }
}
```

In `VtexSkuAttributeValues` class you can declare:

```
public static final String DEF_NMS = "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Vtex.Commerce.WebApps.AdminWcfService.Contracts";
```

and use it for every class and field where it should be used as default namespace. For example:

```
@JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "StockKeepingUnitFieldNameDTO", namespace = DEF_NMS)
```

For properties, for which you do not want to change name you can use:

```
@JacksonXmlProperty(namespace = VtexSkuAttributeValues.DEF_NMS)
```

Above code prints for some random data:

```
<listStockKeepingUnitName>
  <StockKeepingUnitFieldNameDTO xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Vtex.Commerce.WebApps.AdminWcfService.Contracts">
    <fieldName>Name1</fieldName>
    <fieldValues>
      <a:string xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">6184</a:string>
    </fieldValues>
    <idSku>123</idSku>
  </StockKeepingUnitFieldNameDTO>
  <StockKeepingUnitFieldNameDTO xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Vtex.Commerce.WebApps.AdminWcfService.Contracts">
    <fieldName>Name1</fieldName>
    <fieldValues>
      <a:string xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">6184</a:string>
    </fieldValues>
    <idSku>123</idSku>
  </StockKeepingUnitFieldNameDTO>
</listStockKeepingUnitName>
```

If it is not what you want you can play with that code and try other methods which are available for you to configure this instance.

To create this example `Jackson` in version `2.9.9` was used.

Comment: This is a very nice example that shows the inner workings of Jackson XML, and now I feel I should've worded my question better. Is there a way to completely prevent Jackson from adding a prefix to the namespace? If I set an empty string as the prefix, Jackson defaults to `wstxns`. If I set it to null, I get `NullPointerException`

Comment: @Morgan, `Jackson` is just a wrapper for other library, in that case for [woodstox](https://github.com/FasterXML/woodstox). But, generally you can not have more than one default namespace in global scope at the same time. To write default namespace `xmlns` without prefixes is used. If you want to have always `xmlns` without any prefixes you need to change default namespace during serialisation, so on each level whenever namespace is needed we need to set it to default. I thought that my example will allow you to generate an acceptable `XML`.

Comment: @Morgan, take a look at [Woodstox : Bind Namespace Prefix and URI During XML Generation Using StAX](http://www.studytrails.com/java/xml/woodstox/java-xml-woodstox-xml-generation-bind-prefix/), read about `NamespaceContext` class and how to use it. See [Avoid namespace while Parsing xml with woodstox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53700912/avoid-namespace-while-parsing-xml-with-woodstox), [Understanding StAX: how to correctly use XMLStreamWriter](http://veithen.io/2009/11/01/understanding-stax.html)

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be the missing piece. It allows you to set the prefix and namespace.

```
   static class NamespaceXmlFactory extends XmlFactory {

    private final String defaultNamespace;
    private final Map<String, String> prefix2Namespace;

    public NamespaceXmlFactory(String defaultNamespace, Map<String, String> prefix2Namespace) {
        this.defaultNamespace = Objects.requireNonNull(defaultNamespace);
        this.prefix2Namespace = Objects.requireNonNull(prefix2Namespace);
    }

    @Override
    protected XMLStreamWriter _createXmlWriter(IOContext ctxt, Writer w) throws IOException {
        XMLStreamWriter2 writer = (XMLStreamWriter2)super._createXmlWriter(ctxt, w);
        try {
            writer.setDefaultNamespace(defaultNamespace);
            writer.setPrefix("xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
            for (Map.Entry<String, String> e : prefix2Namespace.entrySet()) {
                writer.setPrefix(e.getKey(), e.getValue());
            }
        } catch (XMLStreamException e) {
            StaxUtil.throwAsGenerationException(e, null);
        }
        return writer;
    }
}
```

The only remaining issue I have is

```
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "@xsi.type", isAttribute = true, namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance")
@JsonProperty("@xsi.type")
private String type;
```

Creates the following output:

> 

Still trying to resolve how to make it be xsi:type="networkObjectGroupDTO" instead.

Comment: Yes, I know the constructor is useless in the above code. It was for testing

Answer (score 0):

To add on the existing answers, the `XmlFactory` can also be used with `createGenerator`, in which case the provided solutions would not work.

This is the case when using Spring's `MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter`.

Here is my solution (in Kotlin):

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonEncoding
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.io.IOContext
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.XmlFactory
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.ser.ToXmlGenerator
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.util.StaxUtil
import java.io.File
import java.io.OutputStream
import java.io.Writer
import javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException
import javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamWriter


class NamespaceXmlFactory(
  private val defaultNamespace: String? = null,
  private val prefixToNamespace: Map<String, String> = emptyMap(),
) : XmlFactory() {

  override fun _createXmlWriter(ctxt: IOContext?, w: Writer?): XMLStreamWriter =
    super._createXmlWriter(ctxt, w).apply { configure() }

  override fun createGenerator(out: OutputStream?, enc: JsonEncoding?): ToXmlGenerator =
    super.createGenerator(out, enc).apply { staxWriter.configure() }

  override fun createGenerator(out: OutputStream?): ToXmlGenerator =
    super.createGenerator(out).apply { staxWriter.configure() }

  override fun createGenerator(out: Writer?): ToXmlGenerator =
    super.createGenerator(out).apply { staxWriter.configure() }

  override fun createGenerator(f: File?, enc: JsonEncoding?): ToXmlGenerator =
    super.createGenerator(f, enc).apply { staxWriter.configure() }

  override fun createGenerator(sw: XMLStreamWriter?): ToXmlGenerator =
    super.createGenerator(sw).apply { staxWriter.configure() }

  private fun XMLStreamWriter.configure() =
    try {
      defaultNamespace?.let { this.setDefaultNamespace(it) }
      for ((key, value) in prefixToNamespace) {
        this.setPrefix(key, value)
      }
    } catch (e: XMLStreamException) {
      StaxUtil.throwAsGenerationException(e, null)
    }
}
```