# How to specify Namespace with Jackson XmlMapper()

Tags: jackson, xml-namespaces, woodstox

I have a POJO that I need to parse to XML. I'm using Jackson 2.10.

I pass my Object and parse as follows:

```
    ObjectMapper mapper = new XmlMapper(); 
    mapper.enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);        
    byte[] val = mapper.writeValueAsBytes(infoToPost);
    System.out.println(mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(infoToPost));
```

My output has xmlns:wstxnsl. I would like to have it be xmlns:xsi followed by the xsi:type"".

I believe this is because woodstox is used as default. I need to change it.

What do i need to do to make this happen with Jackson?

Desired Output:

```
<network_object xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="subnetNetworkObjectDTO">
```

Actual Output

```
<wstxns1:network_objects xmlns:wstxns1="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
```

Comment: Take a look at this question [Prevent Jackson XML mapper from adding wstxns to namespaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58052669/prevent-jackson-xml-mapper-from-adding-wstxns-to-namespaces). It shows how to configure namespace prefixes for inner classes. Could you show your `POJO` model with all annotations? Without model is hard to guess what do you expect generally. Could you create a simple usage of all classes and what is expected? What is `network_object` and what is `subnetNetworkObjectDTO`?

Comment: Original question suggests some misunderstanding of XML namespaces, since desired and actual output have different actual bound namespaces (and then logical content), they are not equivalent. Jackson itself allows definition of namespaces to bind (although not prefixes to use).